# Oracle Datetime difference issue with AM/ PM

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have the following stored procedure which calculates the time taken for a merge statement

```
create or replace procedure ModAuditData(
O_UpdatedCount out int
,O_EndTime out timestamp 
,O_Duration out int)
as


   P_StartTime timestamp(3) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE;
  -- EndTime timestamp; 

  begin
    P_StartTime:=to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS');
   -- merge Statment that does UPSERT 
    O_UpdatedCount :=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    commit;

    O_EndTime:=to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS');
    begin 
      select extract( second from (O_EndTime-P_StartTime) )
      into O_Duration
      from dual;
          Exception When others then
      O_Duration:=0;
   end;

  end ModAuditData;
```

The Issue is

```
O_EndTime:=to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

gives exact opposite of

```
P_StartTime:=to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS');
```

in terms of AM/PM

What is the correct way to calculate the start and end time

Comment: What is the significance of converting a timestamp to char and again to timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is already a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, there is no reason to convert it first to VARCHAR2 and then back again into a TIMESTAMP.

Also `timestamp(3)` (which provides precision up to millisecond) does not make much sense when you return duration as INTEGER, i.e. full seconds.

Try it like this:

```
   P_StartTime timestamp(3) WITH TIME ZONE;

  begin
    P_StartTime := current_timestamp;
   -- merge Statment that does UPSERT 
    O_UpdatedCount :=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    commit;

    O_Duration := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (current_timestamp - P_StartTime));
   end;
```

In case of SQL*Plus consider to use [TIMING](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve047.htm#SQPUG130) command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer